# How to implement an xml saveable/loadable class?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, xml-serialization

I would like to create a class, which would be loadable and saveable to an XML file. I want to use one class which is doing the loading task and I want to integrate it with the actual class that I want to save and load, everything seems to be doable up to the point where JAVA doesn't allow the class instance to be change from within the class, i.e. there is no:

```
this = JAXBLoader.load();
```

So currently that's the problem I'm facing.

And I want to be able to control the loading and saving it via the public methods from the class itself, so that from the outside I don't need any factories or managers to load it. Currently the only solution I've seen to this was if I extended the class that I want to save as an xml and then delegate all the methods to the intance of the actual class and then when loading a new instance from the file, the instance would get replaced. But it is a bit of overhead to have to delegate all of the methods, especially pain in the ass if you need to add new methods to the class and have multiple implementations...

So are there any good practices or patterns on achieving something similar or solving the problem I demonstrated above? Actually I'm open, if somebody can overall share what are the best ways to do class saving and loading the easiest ways I would really glad about it.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "factories or managers"?

Comment: @lexicore Well, in some cases I guess I want to avoid extra dependencies to other classes like factories or other managers and allow the saving to be done on the class pretty often, like after every manipulation or similar cases. I'd appreciate if you'd comment. Though I know that sometimes design can be done differently, but I guess in some cases it's better to do this way.

Comment: You don't avoid dependencies if you're using some marshalling/unmarshalling framework, hiding access to that from your class. You still have the dependencies, they are just implicit, which is even worse. It is possible to put the while unmarshalling/marshalling code into the class itself, that would be self-contained then. But this will be a mess. JAXB 1 did it that way, and that *was* a mess. And even if you did XML, then you'll maybe need JSON, PBF, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why do you want to avoid external factories and managers. For me it seems quite natural to extract serialization and not handle it in the model classes themselves. But okay.

What I understood is that your core problem is to load data into `this` instance. Here's a simple way to achieve this with JAXB.

I'm the author of [JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/), a plugin package for JAXB/XJC. It contains the `copyable` plugin which generates a few `copyTo` methods in the schema-derived classes.

This will give you methods like [`copyTo(Object target)`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/lang/CopyTo2.java#L9). With this you can first unmarshal data from XML into some temporary instance and then `copyTo(this)`. Something like:

```
MyType temporaryInstance = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, MyType.class).getValue();
temporaryInstance.copyTo(this);
```

You can add this method to your schema-derived code via code injection or by subclassing.

Comment: This answer looks really good! It's very informative, tells the overall picture (that you would be OK for external factories to do the loading) and presents the solution to my problem! Thank you very much. I'll try that out in the next couple of days and will accept this answer! :)